# Xcode build codesigns all the pods frameworks on every debug build, taking a lot of time

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8, code-signing

I've just joined an iOS project (Xcode 8.2, iOS SDK 10.2, minimum target 8.0) that has over 20 pods (which uses frameworks). Whenever I was building the project, I've noticed that "Running 4 of 4 custom shell scripts" phase was taking way too long, about 15 to 20 seconds. I've watched the logs when Xcode is at that phase and realized that it was codesigning all the pod frameworks one by one, each taking just a bit under 1 second. This happens on *every* build (not just the first time after cleaning, it even happens when I don't change **anything at all** and hit Run again), and yes, I'm talking about *debug* builds. The project has Xcode-managed codesigning.

I've never encountered any problem with any other projects (and all have framework pods and Xcode-managed signing with many pods, pretty much the same configuration with this one), the problem is only with this particular project.

Why would this be happening?